# ошибка syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Tags: linux, git-bash

При попытке выполнить в терминале Ubuntu20

```
User:$ ./index.html
```

получил ошибку:

> ./index.html: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'
> ./index.html: line 1: ''

Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: А почему вы решили, что этот файл в принципе можно выполнять?

Comment: Он исполняемый. При его открытии должна открываться страница в браузере

Comment: Почему вы решили, что должна? Чтобы открывался браузер — нужно выполнять именно браузер, а не произвольный текстовый файл.

Comment: В винде при запуске подобного файла открывается браузер по умолчанию и открывается страница на localhost. И проблема мне видится не в этом (пока), а в том, что при попытке выполнить этот файл обнаруживается синтаксическая ошибка в нем.

Comment: Ну так винда это не линукс, она пытается быть умнее пользователя и автоматически особым образом обрабатывает файлы, которые нельзя выполнять. Линукс же покорно слушается вас, и если вы приказываете выполнять файл — он будет пытаться его выполнять и выдавать вам ошибку, потому что html-файлы не являются программами и их невозможно выполнять.

Comment: Кроме того, в линуксе не существует понятия «браузер по умолчанию». Если вы установили и настроили среду рабочего стола, которая соблюдает спецификации XDG, вы можете попробовать использовать команду `xdg-open`, которая попытается подобрать для указанного файла правильную программу, которая соответствует предпочтениям текущего пользователя (и скорее всего это окажется «браузер по умолчанию»)

Comment: Спасибо. Я еще не устанавливал среду рабочего стола, учусь работать в терминале

Comment: В Ubuntu20 по умолчанию идёт среда рабочего стола GNOME — она у вас уже установлена, если вы её не удаляли специально.

Comment: Я Ubuntu20 установил через командную строку винды (wsl2). При запуске показывает окно терминала. Буду разбираться. Еще раз спасибо

Comment: Если вдруг вы хотите открыть файл из виртуальной машины линукса в браузере на реальной винде, то это всё намного усложняет дело...

Comment: Это я уже понял

Comment: Для WSL существует набор утилит [wslu](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu), которые позволяют плотнее интегрировать виртуальную машину с виндой, и среди них есть утилита `wslview`, которая вроде как позволяет открывать виндовый браузер изнутри WSL. Но у меня сейчас нет WSL под рукой и работоспособность я не проверял

Comment: Попробую проверить

Comment: Попробовал:  xdg-open index.html
Start : ╨Э╨╡ ╤Г╨┤.....: ╨Э╨╡ ╤Г╨┤╨░╨╡╤В╤Б╤П ╨╜╨░╨╣╤В╨╕ ╤Г╨║╨░╨╖╨░╨╜╨╜╤Л╨╣ ╤Д╨░╨╣╨╗.
╤Б╤В╤А╨╛╨║╨░:1 ╨╖╨╜╨░╨║:1
+ Start "/home/..../work/Hello/index.html"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
Судя по-всему, программа попыталась обратиться к PowerShell через wslview, а у той что-то не задалось